# can a singleton class extend Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am using a singleton class to store global variables for the entire project. Also, to host some common functions which several classes/Activities may use, such as launching an alertBuilder window. But in order to do that... I need my singleton to extend Activity like this:

```
public class dataBaseObject extends Activity {
```

I tried to extend application, but that won't allow me to do this:

```
    View view  = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutType, null);
```

therefore, can someone tell me if there are any hidden pitfalls of extending Activity for a singleton ?

Comment: Use static method without extending Activity and pass current Activity's context to it every time you want to display Dialog to avoid WindowManager.BadTokenException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make sense for an `Activity` class to be a singleton, because instances of `Activity` are instantiated by the android system.

What you can do is make an abstract class that extends `Activity`, like this

```
public abstract class AbstractActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int EXAMPLE_CONSTANT = 345;

    public final void exampleMethod() {
         ...
    }

    // This may not be needed
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        ....
    }
}
```

Then you can make all of your activity classes extend `AbstractActivity`. You do not need to declare an abstract class like this in `manifest.xml`.

An alternative solution is to make all of your utility methods have a parameter that is an `Activity` or a `Context` and pass `this` to these methods.